# Elastic search azure deployment log-stash details

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to deploy ElasticSearch on Azure Cloud. Installed the Elastic template from Azure Marketplace and able to access in kibana by hitting this url http://ipaddress:5601 with user id and password given at the time of creation.
Also able to access elastic search http://ipaddress:9200/ and getting below configuration

```
{
  "name" : "myesclient-1",
  "cluster_name" : "myes",
  "cluster_uuid" : "........",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.4",
    "build_hash" : "ccec39f",
    "build_date" : "",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now i am facing problem in,
On which VM runs logstash?
How to start logstash?
Where to store the config files and jdbc config file and how to run BAT file periodically. Bat file syntax for normal VM is like

```
Run
cd C:\logstash\logstash-6.2.2\bin
logstash -f C:\Users\basudeb\Desktop\config\jdbc.config
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Elastic Azure ARM template](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace) does not currently deploy Logstash, *only* Elasticsearch and Kibana. There's an [open issue to track](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/issues/157) this. If you feel it would be useful, please +1 the issue :)